# Using MODE for Standard Deviation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mode, mean, outliers, standard-deviation

I'm trying to eliminate outliers of a set using 1.65 (90%) Standard Deviations from the MODE, not MEAN for various reasons I won't go in to now.

Is there a good way of doing this? I assume the built in STDVE() used MEAN. Does anyone know what this is doing under the covers so I can build my own function based on it but for MODE?

Thanks in advance,
Nic

Comment: related? [Adding Mode to this SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044314/adding-mode-to-this-sql)

Comment: don't think so - I can calculate the MODE but not within a Standard Deviation context

Comment: Your question "Does anyone know what this is doing under the covers" prompts me to ask this: what is your current understanding of what the standard deviation **is** ?

Comment: I understand the maths to a reasonable level, but I ask this because if the Function was written in C# I'd "reflector" it to see how it was written in order to create my own version, in theory copying the best practices therein.

Answer (score 1):

Standard deviation (from Wikipedia) is: take the square root of the average of the squared differences of the values from their average value. In your case change "their average value" to their *mode* value.